# Find the standard matrix for a composition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know how to do part a but b is giving me some trouble. 
I know that the composition is $M\circ L=[M][L]$ but the matrices I get for $L$ and $M$ aren't compatible with multiplication.

For matrix L I get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-4\\2&1&7\end{bmatrix}$$

And by using the rotation standard matrix at $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ I get $M$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that $L$ is correct but these two matrixes aren't compatible with multiplication ($L$ is $2\times3$, $M$ is $2\times2$). Have I missed something with matrix $M$?

Here is a link to a photo of the entire question: 
[Question Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRumW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrices are in fact compatible with multiplication. $[M]$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $[L]$ is a $2\times 3$ matrix, so you can multiply them:
$$
[M][L] = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & -4\\
2 & 1 & 7
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 7\\
-1 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$